# Distinguishing between html divs using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-select

Both of the `select`'s below in the HTML are affected by the same CSS code, however I need to apply different CSS codes to affect both the `select`'s differently. How do I go about doing this? Specifically, I need different `content` properties for each. Currently, all selects have all these CSS attributes.

CSS:

```
&.has-value:not(.is-open) {
    .Select-input {
        position: relative;

        &::before {
            content: '+ Add';
            position: absolute;
            font-style: italic;
            left: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            color: #bbb;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="job-desc-item">
    <h4 className="section-heading">Skills:</h4>
    <Select
        multi
        simpleValue
        value={this.state.skillValue}
        placeholder="+ Add skill"
        options={this.state.skillOptions}
        clearable={false}
        autosize={false}
        onChange={this.handleSkillsSelectChange.bind(this)}
    />
</div>
<div className="job-desc-item">
    <h4 className="section-heading">Location:</h4>
    <Select
        multi
        simpleValue
        value={this.state.locationValue}
        placeholder="+ Add location"
        options={this.state.locationOptions}
        clearable={false}
        autosize={false}
        onChange={this.handleLocationSelectChange.bind(this)}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: give them a unique class and overwrite `content` using the unique class? Or target `.job-desc-item:first-child .Select-Input::before` and/or `.job-desc-item:last-child .Select-Input::before`

Comment: If I have multiple class names, then I would have a lot of repeated css code just to change one attribute. Same issue with the childs

Comment: Not at all. Use the CSS you have there, then simply add one rule of `.someClass::before { content: 'whatever'; }` or `.job-desc-item:last-child::before { content: 'whatever'; }`. You're going to have to add another rule to change the content, I don't know how you could possibly do it with less code than that.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome. Submitted an answer. Let me know if I screwed up the scss :) I don't use it very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either give them a unique class, or use the `:nth-child()` selectors to select unique parents. Use your existing CSS, then add a rule for the element `content` you want to change using the class or `:nth-child()` selector.

Class

```
.Select-input {
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: '+ Add';
    position: absolute;
    font-style: italic;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    color: #bbb;
  }
  &.unique-class::before {
    content: 'some content';
  }
}
```

`:nth-child()`

```
.Select-input {
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: '+ Add';
    position: absolute;
    font-style: italic;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    color: #bbb;
  }
}
.job-desc-item:last-child() .Select-input::before {
  content: 'some content';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple question with a simple answer, or a very complex matter I can't understand. For the simple case, I would say you could try setting id property on the selects, or using class property to specify different class names for them. On both cases, you would only need to write new CSS rules for that selectors.

If the question is about a more complex case than I could realize, please, explain it in more detail to try to help you

Comment: It's probably simple I'm new to this. If I have multiple class names, then I would have a lot of repeated css code just to change one attribute, is there any way around this? Btw, that css code is just a portion of the "tree" for this div

Comment: I think you should take a look at CSS basics, and how css rules are applied, how styles are inherited from parent elements, etc ... Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

BTW, I think the CSS code you pasted is not "pure" CSS, but SASS

Comment: Right, I get that. I just don't want to have repeat CSS code everywhere (because the different classes would have the same attributes for the most part) I just feel like theres a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Also its SCSS not SASS

Answer (score 0):

Just use `:nth-child` to select them as needed for CSS. [More details here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

It'll look like

```
.job-desc-item:nth-child(1) {
 /* your css */
}

.job-desc-item:nth-child(2) {
 /* your css */
}
```

Comment: So I would have to repeat all the css code just to change one attribute? there is more code in the "tree" btw so it would be a lot of repeated code

Comment: No, you could do multiples of n or whatever other calculation of n you'd like to use in order to affect everything in the tree